# is there a slipcase for 17" MacBook Pros which opens at the side?

Tags: macbook-pro

I carry my 17" MBP in my laptop pannier, into which it just fits in portrait orientation.  I'd like to protect it with a slipcase, but I don't want to have to take the slipcase out of the pannier to get at the laptop.  Is there a slipcase on the market that opens at the side?

Comment: my wife makes custom ones... mine is blue corduroy and opens on the long side.  just saying :P

Answer (score 1):

I've certainly seen them around the place, I've got a portrait one myself.

How about [this](http://www.luggage.com/Slappa-SL-NSV-11White-SLA1097.html)?